# Can anyone suggest me how to do a location based search from MySQL database using Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, geolocation

I want to fetch several row data from the database of stores(let's say) according to a particular point(latitude, longitude) and a radius(let's say R) around that point. I am using Spring Boot and Spring Data JPA and MySql as database.

Can you suggest some technology or some feature of spring which will allow me to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given you have latitude and longitude coordinates stored in your database:

1. Find all stores and their coodrdinates in your database.
2. Calculate distance to your given point and map the distance to your stores; these math formulas might be helpful: https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html
3. Filter stores with distance closer than your given R.